# Database design for products with multiple units

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am designing a database for retail business using Sql server as backend. There are some products that can be sold in multiple units, for example, pencils can be sold in ea and dozen, paper can be sold in sheet, ream, and canton. Basically, each product can be sold in more than one unit.

The App needs to supports

- Can receive products from suppliers in many unit. Sometime we might
  order 1 pencil and the next time we order 2 boxes of pencil.
- Can sell products in multiple unit, for example, we must be able to
  sell 1 box and 2 pencils in the same bill.
- App also need supports for FIFO or LIFO

Below is my initial design

```
Table: Products
ProductId | Barcode | Name   | BaseUnitId
1         | XXXX    | Pencil | 1

Table: Units
UnitId | Name
1      | Each / Pieces
2      | Box

Table: UnitConversion
ProductId | BaseUnitId | Multiplier | ToUnitId |
1         | 1          | 24         | 2        | // 24 pencils in a box

Table: Inventories
Id | ProductId | UnitId | Quantity 
1  | 1         | 1          | 48                //In pieces

Table Invoices
Id | ProductId | UnitId | Quantity
1  | 1         | 2      | 1.5                   //Sold/Purchased 1.5 boxes that means 18 pieces
```

Is there any flaws in my design? Is there anything that I miss? This can't be a new problem. Does anyone have any ideas (or examples)?

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/121436

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a few suggestions:

1. It seems like you could remove the UnitConversion table and just store the Multiplier value against the Unit record (so you'd store 1 against Each / Pieces and 24 against Box). Then the conversion would just be the 'From' unit's quantity divided by the 'To' unit's quantity.
2. Is is possible that different units would have different barcodes? If so, the barcode could be stored against the Unit record instead.
3. In your Inventories and Invoices tables, the ProductId column might be unnecessary as you could get this by joining Units table.
4. To support FIFO or LIFO, you're going to need to store more specific information about your stock, so there's some way of knowing the date it was booked in, the quantity remaining, and maybe some way of identifying that specific item (or group of items).

Hope this helps!

EDIT: Your Inventories table could look something like this:

```
Id | UnitId | [identifier] | CurrentQuantity | DateAdded
1  | 1      | ABC123       | 20              | 2017-01-10
2  | 1      | ABC124       | 96              | 2017-01-12
```

The [identifier] column (name's up to you!) would store some way of identifying the physical stock, this could be something that the users assign on receipt of the item, or maybe their suppliers would already have added some that could be used.

To implement FIFO in a scenario where someone wants to buy 24 pencils, you know you need to take 20 from the group of items labelled 'ABC123' and 4 labelled 'ABC124'.

Comment: Thanks @sam..Can u pls provide rough diagram of inventory table..So that I can understand LIFO or with different barcodes?

Comment: Thank u very much @sam